# $_POST data manipulation 'delay'

Tags: php, post

I am using `$_POST` to post data back to a field before manipulating it again. However the functionality is not what I desire.

```
// Default to current date
if(!isset($_POST['inputText3'])) {
    $input = '2014';
} else {
    // grab input
    $input = $_POST['inputText3'];
}

// manipulation to run each time
$input = $input + 1;

if(isset($_POST['year1']) || isset($_POST['year2'])) {

    // Do more complex stuff - but simplified (duplicated) below for this example
    echo '<form method="post" action="">';
    echo '<button type="submit" name="year1" value="2016" class="button">2016</button>';
    echo '<button type="submit" name="year2" value="2017" class="button">2017</button>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="inputText3" value="' . $input . '">';
    echo '</form>';
} else {

    echo '<form method="post" action="">';
    echo '<button type="submit" name="year1" value="2016" class="button">2016</button>';
    echo '<button type="submit" name="year2" value="2017" class="button">2017</button>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="inputText3" value="' . $input . '">';
    echo '</form>';
}
```

Initially on first page load, my function grabs an inital value from `input3` (2014), manipulates it (+1) and then outputs it back to the input field (2015). This is what I want.

What I want to happen next, is when a button (generated by the PHP) is clicked, to do the same again.

Instead, on button click, the page reloads and grabs the **original** value from `input3` (2014) - despite the fact that the manipulated value (2015) is visible in `input3`.

This means my page has a click 'delay'. 
I think the issue is using the code below incorrectly:

```
if(!isset($_POST['inputText3'])) {
    $input = '2014';
} else {
    //get posts date
    $input = $_POST['inputText3'];
}
```

Are sessions an option? Can they be used when posting to the same page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-read your question now that you're clearer; Try this -

```
<?php 

$input = (isset($_POST['lastYear'])) ? "$_POST[lastYear]" : '2014';

if (isset($_POST['year']) AND $_POST['year'] == 1) {
$input++;
} elseif (isset($_POST['year']) AND $_POST['year'] == 2) {
$input += 2;
}   

echo $input;
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
<input type="radio" name="year" value="1"> - Add 1 year<Br>
<input type="radio" name="year" value="2"> - Add 2 years<Br>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $input ?>" name="lastYear">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Edit: Whoops had 2013 instead of 2014 :)

Comment: I've edited; Try now. Thanks for clearing the issue up. Note its best practice not to echo out HTML and instead close and open PHP tags around it

Answer (score 0):

`=` i think this is problem.. there should be `==`.

you are giving value by assign `=` this.

if you are comparing (ternary operator) you should used `==`

```
 $cur_year= 2014;
 if(!isset($_POST['inputText3'])) {
        $input = ($cur_year=='2014')?$_POST['inputText3'] :'2014';
    } else {
        //get posts date
        $input == isset($_POST['inputText3']) ?$_POST['inputText3'] :'';
    }
```

Comment: I am not comparing anything? I am assigning the `$input` variable to the variable returned by `$_POST`

Comment: @myol i think you writes ternary operator in wrong way instead of true of false you are assigning value, directly. `echo (true)  ? "yes" : "no";    //prints yes` in your case **where is true or false condition** your else condition is right but if condition is not right

Comment: I am totally lost at what you are trying to explain.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my answer. But it is still a seperate issue.

Comment: `==` is the comparison operator for equal to. Your solution is incorrect. `=` is for assigning values, in this case the OPs code is correct.

Comment: @iamgory - My initial code was flawed but still worked. My edit has cleared up any misunderstandings (I hope)

Comment: @myol i think your problem is that `$input` is not increment every time? how could `$input` store value? once the page refreshed you lost your assign value.

Comment: Not much he can do without storing it in a database